# Amend Linq projection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Let's say I've got a flat model (`MyModel`) with 26 properties (`A`, `B`, `C`, ...). Let's pretend that I can display this model on a screen and that most of my customers only care about the consonants, which is convenient because bringing the vowels from the database is very time consuming. As of now, I've got two legacy projections:

```
public IQueryable<MyModel> GetOnlyConsonants()
{
    return Context.Entities.AlphabetSet.Select(set => new MyModel {
         B = set.B,
         C = set.C,
         //And so forth, bringing back all the consonants
    })
}

public IQueryable<MyModel> GetAllAlphabet()
{
    return Context.Entities.AlphabetSet.Select(set => new MyModel {
         B = set.B,
         C = set.C,
         //And so forth, bringing back all the consonants

         // This part is time consuming
         A = set.A,
         E = set.E,         
         I = set.I,
         O = set.O,
         U = set.U
    })
}
```

Now if I extend `MyModel` to add ten new properties that I want in both my projection (zero, one, two ... nine), how can I avoid to add it to both of the projections? Is there a way to merge the common part and only amend the vowels when needed to avoid redundancy?

Comment: This is where using something like AutoMapper could come in handy. The mappings could be configured to use parameters to conditionally map.

Answer (score 0):

The properties in `MyModel` do not impact the current projections. I would simply create a new method like `GetOnlyNumbers`. Note `GetOnlyConsonants` does not bring in the rest of the alphabet, because it only includes consonants in the projection.

```cs
public IQueryable<MyModel> GetOnlyNumbers() // generic query
{
    return Context.Entities.AlphabetSet.Select(set => new MyModel {
         Zero = set.Zero,
         One = set.One,
         // ...
    })
}
```

Comment: what if I want to be able to retrieve all the alphabet and the numbers? 3 different projections and a merge of those three? Which means 3 round-trips to the DB :/ Or do you think of something else?

Comment: 3 round trips is needed as long as your queries remain generic. What I have seen is a specific query that only projects what you need to optimize the number of round trips.